# Has anyone ever proposed a relational mathematical universe?

Tags: axioms, philosophy

We know from Gödel's incompleteness theorems that any significantly powerful axiomatic system is either inconsistent or incomplete, and we even have a few examples where the ZFC comes short. As you try to fill in all the missing patches so to speak, you need more and more axioms.

In physics (relativity and quantum mechanics for example), it's been found that a relational approach (seems) necessary to explain observation. Grete Hermann, for example, introduced the relational concept for quantum mechanics where state and quantity are only meaningful under the context of relations between systems,and where the physical nature of a QM universe is understood as the set of all relations.

Has anyone proposed something of this sort as foundation for mathematics?

Comment: Roughly, quantum mechanics relies on states --- for logic, presumably "true" and "false" --- and makes them stochastic, to rationalize observed puzzles for classical mechanics.  If someone told me a theorem was true with probability .875 I would have little interest in talking to them further.  Godel's theorem doesn't state that we can't figure out if something is true or false, it says it is not decidable, it's neither. Tagging such propositions with a probability does not seem intellectually satisfying to me.

Comment: The relational concept in QM doesn't presuppose or imply that the universe isn't deterministic. That was the point of the relational view in the beginning, to explain how QM could be both deterministic and unpredictable at the same time. What I'm curious about in terms of a foundation of mathematics, is just whether the concepts of relation can be used in a fundamental way as it has in physics; not thinking it should resemble those physical theories directly, and definitely not with probabilities.

Comment: For example, perhaps using such a relational foundation, some propositions would be neither independent, nor decidable (with a Turing machine).